# Error al correr javascript sin iframe

Tags: javascript, java

Tengo un problema al correr el mismo script en 2 paginas diferentes, lo que sucede es que en una pagina con iframe este corre normal , me saltan todos los alert que he puesto (los alert los puse para ver hasta que parte del script se ejecutabat).

Ahora cuando uso el script en una pagina sin iframes por alguna razon solo corre hasta el alert("parte2"), alguien sabe la razon ?

```
<script>
function permisosMenu() {
var cadena = <%=permisos%>
//alert(cadena);
alert("parte1");
  if(!cadena.includes(1) && !cadena.includes(2) && !cadena.includes(3) && !cadena.includes(4) && !cadena.includes(26))
        document.getElementById("bloque1").style.display ="none";
  alert("parte2");
  if(!cadena.includes(5) && !cadena.includes(6) && !cadena.includes(7) && !cadena.includes(8) &&
          !cadena.includes(9) && !cadena.includes(10) && !cadena.includes(11) && !cadena.includes(12) &&
          !cadena.includes(13) && !cadena.includes(14) && !cadena.includes(15) && !cadena.includes(16) && 
          !cadena.includes(27) && !cadena.includes(28))
        document.getElementById("bloque2").style.display ="none";
  alert("parte3");
  if(!cadena.includes(6) && !cadena.includes(7) && !cadena.includes(8) && !cadena.includes(9) 
          && !cadena.includes(10) && !cadena.includes(11) && !cadena.includes(12) && !cadena.includes(27) &&
          !cadena.includes(28))
        document.getElementById("bloque2_op2").style.display ="none";
  alert("parte4");
  if(!cadena.includes(17) && !cadena.includes(18) && !cadena.includes(19) && !cadena.includes(20) )
        document.getElementById("bloque3").style.display ="none";
  alert("parte5");
  if(!cadena.includes(21) && !cadena.includes(22) && !cadena.includes(23))
        document.getElementById("bloque4").style.display ="none";
  alert("parte6");
  if(!cadena.includes(24) && !cadena.includes(25))
        document.getElementById("bloque5").style.display ="none";
  alert("partefinal");
  for (var i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {
      if(!cadena.includes(i)){
        //alert("op"+i);
        document.getElementById("op"+i).style.display ="none";
    }
}   
}
</script>
```

El script es llamado por un onload en el body en ambos casos

Comment: despues de hacer el alert(2) que error te arroja en la consola?

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav aparece lo siguiente:  Cannot read property 'style' of null